# PHP echoing a specific field from a table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly, I'm quite new to PHP having only dived in some three weeks ago but loving it as a new thing to learn! I have a specific problem that I cannot seem to find a solution for via Google. I'm running a test page that will form the basis of a final product for a local recreational club that runs competitions and wants to display the results online on their website.

I've created a MySQL database and called it 'results' and imported as a CSV a sample of competition results. My code to connect to the database works as the page displays the "Database Connection Established" message.

The database contains a table called 'z_any_year_results' and the table structure looks like this:-

Record_Number        Field                        Value
1                                Field_1                        Value_1
2                                Field_2                        Value_2
3                                Field_3                        Value_3
4                                Field_4                        Value_4
5                                Field_5                        Value_5

I understand how to select the specific table using

```
mysql_select_db("results") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT z_any_year_results FROM results")
```

but I need to echo a specific field from the table in a specific section of the web page. So for example, in one section of the page I need to output the field containing the value Field_1 and nearby on the page the field containing the value Value_1. But in another section of the page I need to output the field with the value Field_4 and nearby on the page, the field containing the value Value_4. So I guess my problem is how to extract a specific piece of data from a table to the exclusion of all other records in the table and outout it as an echo on the web page. I cannot find anything on the web that is written in a simple step-by-stepway to help novices like myself understand.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. Read about `PDO`.

Comment: use this statement: `select field_name from z_any_year_results`

Comment: Hi fabricator,Thanks - that's a start.  So if for example I want to output Value_2 as an echo, how would I write your suggestion that selects the sencond row, third column field?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a type of data design known as key/value design. In other words, each row has the name of a data item and its value. That's not an ideal sort of design for a beginner to use, because it makes for fairly intricate queries.

To answer your question, if you want a certain named field's value you use this query.

```
SELECT Value FROM z_any_year_results WHERE Name = 'Field4'
```

But, maybe you want a design that resembles your application's entities a little more closely.

You might have an entity, a table, called, `contestant`, another called `contest`, and another called `prize`.

`contestant` is a table with columns like `contestant_id`, `surname`, `givenname`,  `email`  etc
   e.g.  1 ,  Ellison, Larry, larry@oracle.com

Then you can use queries like `SELECT * FROM contest WHERE YEAR(datestart) = 2016` which will make your queries more closely reflect the logic of your application.

Comment: Hi Ollie,
Clearly I'm out of my depth!  So the original example I posted needs to be the basis of a template to apply to other competition pages.  These pages will connect to a different table with the same structure but the values in the fields in the FIELD column and VALUE column might be completely different.  Does that make sense?